# Compare two arrays with same length but having different object id's inside in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to compare two arrays of objects having different integer id's inside, like below.

```
    arrayOne = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; 
    arrayTwo = [{id: 42}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}];  // should return false on it because 42 is not in first array.
```

I wanted to implement a function that should return `false` if these two arrays are not identical like the above example but if these two arrays are identical like below it should return `true`,

```
    arrayOne = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; 
    arrayTwo = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; // should return true on it because both are identical.

    arrayOne = [{id: 35}, {id: 43}, {id: 45}]; 
    arrayTwo = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; // should return true on it because all id's are inside.
```

Any good approach to achieve this?

Comment: Use `Array.every` for that, like this:`arrayOne.every(k=>arrayTwo.some(d=>d.id==k.id))`

Comment: for this, I need sorted array or not?

Comment: I have answered, let me know if it helps you. Also you need not to do sorting for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `every` and inside it check if item exists in other array using `some`:

```js
arrayOne = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; 
arrayTwo = [{id: 42}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}];

result1 = arrayOne.every(k=>arrayTwo.some(d=>d.id==k.id));

console.log(result1);

//Second case

arrayOne = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; 
arrayTwo = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}];

result2 = arrayOne.every(k=>arrayTwo.some(d=>d.id==k.id));

console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Will, it covers my second use case in true?

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar Yes, it will.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the stringified array:

```js
var arrayOne = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; 
var arrayTwo = [{id: 42}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}];

function isSame(arrayOne, arrayTwo){
  return JSON.stringify(arrayOne) == JSON.stringify(arrayTwo)? true : false;
}
console.log(isSame(arrayOne,arrayTwo));

arrayOne = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; 
arrayTwo = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}];
console.log(isSame(arrayOne,arrayTwo));
```

Update: If you want the result to be true for the values irrespective of the index then you can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var arrayOne = [{id: 35}, {id: 43}, {id: 45}]; 
var arrayTwo = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}]; 

function isSame(arrayOne, arrayTwo){
  return arrayOne.every(i => arrayTwo.some(j => j.id == i.id));
}
console.log(isSame(arrayOne,arrayTwo));
```

Comment: Will, it covers my second use case in true?

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar, absolutely, updated the answer with the second input, please check:)

Comment: What about in this use case.

    `arrayOne = [{id: 35}, {id: 43}, {id: 45}]; 
    arrayTwo = [{id: 45}, {id: 35}, {id: 43}];`  // should return true on it because all id's are inside

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar, that will return `false`, this will work if they are in order:)

Comment: Your solution does not work if the same id's on different indexes like the above comment.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar, in that case, you have to use `every()` and `some()`, please check the second answer:)

Comment: yeah, trying it with different inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

use `map` on one to gather id's and
use `every` on two.

```js
arrayOne = [{ id: 45 }, { id: 35 }, { id: 43 }];
arrayTwo = [{ id: 42 }, { id: 35 }, { id: 43 }];

const compare = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  const one = arr1.map(({ id }) => id);
  return arr2.every(({ id }) => one.includes(id));
};

console.log(compare(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
```